# How to loop array with Json data

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have an example array get form database column like this :

```
[0] => {"data_1":"content_1","data_2":"content_2"}
[1] => {"data_1":"content_1","data_2":"content_2"}
```

How do i decode this json and loop it in foreach php ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `json_decode()`

Comment: json_decode( $response_string );

Comment: I have tried but after the foreach loop that appears only one data array. Is there any solution?

Comment: please share your full code with foreach loop

Comment: This is my code :
<?php
$nomor = 1;
foreach ($data_array as $data) :
      $data_student = json_decode($data->DATA_STUDENT, true);
?>
<tr>
   <td><?= $nomor; ?></td>
   <td><?= $data_student['data_1']; ?></td>
   <td><?= $data_student['data_2']; ?></td> 
</tr>
<?php 
   $nomor++;
   endforeach; 
?>

Comment: please try my answer. let me know if any issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
$array=array('{"data_1":"content_1","data_2":"content_2"}','{"data_1":"content_1","data_2":"content_2"}');
foreach($array as $a)
{
   $data=json_decode( $a );
    //print_r($data);
    foreach($data as $k=>$d)
    {
        echo $k.':'.$d;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

> Output

```
data_1:content_1
data_2:content_2
data_1:content_1
data_2:content_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may to have to start like this:

```
$JSONGetter = json_decode($GETjson, true);
foreach ($JSONGetter as $value){
$DataContent = $value['data_1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(array_map(function ($value) {
    return json_decode($value, true);
}, [
    0 => '{"data_1":"content_1","data_2":"content_2"}',
    1 => '{"data_1":"content_1","data_2":"content_2"}'
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below code

```
<?php 
     $nomor = 1; 
     foreach ($data_array as $data) : 
        $data_student_array = json_decode($data->DATA_STUDENT, true); ?> 
        <?php
         $nomor1 = 1; 
        foreach($data_student_array as $data_student_value)
        {
            ?>
             <tr> 
                <td><?php echo $nomor1; ?></td> <td><?php echo $data_student_value['data_1']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $data_student_value['data_2']; ?></td> 
           </tr> 
            <?php
            $nomor1++; 
        }
        ?>

       <?php $nomor++; 
    endforeach; 
    ?>
```